# Multiple Username and Password accounts

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, authentication, passwords, login-script

I have the following code to log onto a separate Admin area within my site:

```
<script runat="server">

Public Sub Login(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

If UserName.Text = "admin" And Password.Text = "pw11" Then
Session("Admin") = True
Response.Redirect("default.aspx")

Else

Session("Admin") = False
LtlLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry you have provided incorrect login details.</p>"

End If
End Sub

</script>
```

How can I have it so it has another two or three username and password accounts to log on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private ReadOnly _credentials = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {"admin", "pw11"},
    {"admin1", "pw12"},
    {"admin2", "pw13"}
}

Public Sub Login(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim storedPassword = ""
    If _credentials.TryGetValue(UserName.Text, storedPassword) And storedPassword = Password.Text Then
        Session("Admin") = True
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
    End If

    Session("Admin") = False
    LtlLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry you have provided incorrect login details.</p>"
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much! :-)